# Pass multiple file names captured in a variable to a command (vim)

Tags: bash, vim, grep

I am trying to create a script that opens automatically any files containing a particular pattern.

This is what I achieved so far:

```
xargs -d " " vim < "$(grep --color -r test * | cut -d ':' -f 1 | uniq | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g')"
```

The problem is that vim does not recognize the command as separate file of list, but as a whole filename instead:

```
zsh: file name too long: ..............
```

Is there an easy way to achieve it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to call xargs is just to pass the arguments with newlines via a pipe:

```
grep -Rl test * | xargs vim
```

Note that I'm also passing the `-l` argument to `grep` to list the files that contain my pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
vim -- `grep -rIl test *`
```

- `-I` skip matching in binary files
- `-l` print file name at first match

Try to omit `xargs`, becouse this leads to incorrect behaviour of `vim`:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is append the following line to a list of files:

`> ~/.files.txt && vim $(cat ~/.files.txt | tr "\n" " ")`

For example :

`grep --color -r test *  > ~/.files.txt && vim $(cat ~/.files.txt | tr "\n" " ")`

I have the following in my .bashrc to bind `VV` (twice `V` in uppercase) to insert that automatically :

```
insertinreadline() {
READLINE_LINE=${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$1${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}
    READLINE_POINT=`expr $READLINE_POINT + ${#1}`
}
bind -x '"VV": insertinreadline " > ~/.files.txt &&  vim \$(cat ~/.files.txt | tr \"\\n\" \" \")"'
```